# Terminology: Nonlinear versus curvilinear

Tags: functions, terminology

Consider a simple parabolic function $y=x^2$. Do mathematicians use the word “nonlinear” to describe the curvilinear relationship between $x$ and $y$? If so, is the word “linear” not an umbrella term that includes *curvilinear* and *rectilinear* relationships? Or is “linear” shorthand for *rectilinear*?

I suppose I assumed the opposite of a linear shape was something like a stepwise function, but it seems I might be wrong; because I see many scholarly papers use the word “nonlinear” to refer to curvilinear relationships between variables.

To be sure, my question is not asking about the property of a function being linear in its parameters (e.g., general linear model).